# How can I change the Resources.resw?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, resourcedictionary

i'm writing an Windows 8 App, with c# and Xaml.

At the moment i have two Resource files.

> --local
>
> ----de-DE
>
> ------Resources.resw
>
> ----en-EN
>
> ------Resources.resw

I'm loading the Textparts like this:

```
private ResourceLoader _resources = new ResourceLoader();

_resources.GetString("Menu_Contacts")
```

Now here is my Question, how can I Change the Resources at Runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is setting the `PrimaryLanguageOverride` property:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
```

Note that this will change the language of the application, but your current screen that is already loaded will not refresh. To refresh the text on the current screen, you can implement following event handler:

```
core.ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged 
        += async (s, m) =>
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                settingsLanguageLabel.Text = core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetValue("Resources/SettingsLanguageLabel/Text").ValueAsString;
                settingsRestartLabel.Text = core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetValue("Resources/SettingsRestartLabel/Text").ValueAsString;
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access directly resources keys :

```
Properties.Resources.myResourceKey = "new value";
```

or you can rewrite keys:

```
resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/Resource.resx"));
 foreach (var cnes_ in _ResList)
 {
    resourceWriter.AddResource(cnes_.Key, cnes_.Value);
 }
 resourceWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this approch wasnt usefull for me. I want the Change the Default Resource, but i dont know how.
So that i can Keep using _resources.GetString("Menu_Contacts") , only the Resources.resw File that the command uses should be changed.